# Protractor doesn't run Firefox (only Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, jasmine, protractor, e2e-testing

I'm running Protractor on Chrome. lately I've been trying to run it with Firefox and failed - I don't get any error message, it's just that Chrome runs instead. I think that maybe 'Capabilities' is ignored by Protractor.
my conf file:

```
exports.config = {
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',


suites:{
    sanity: ['*/loginEAPTest.js','*/AccountSettingsTest.js','*/createApptest.js','*/openSourcePageTest.js','*/driveSampleAppTest.js','*/whatsNewTest.js','*/logoutTest.js']

},

specs: ['*/linksTest.js'],

capabilitties:
{

  browserName: 'firefox'

},



//framework: 'jasmine2',

resultJsonOutputFile: 'TestResults/Test_'+dateTime+'.js',

jasmineNodeOpts: {

    isVerbose: true,
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 360000,
    includeStackTrace: true
},


onPrepare: function() {
var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
    consolidateAll: true,
    savePath: 'TestResults',
    filePrefix: 'xmloutput'
}));

// for non-angular page
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(1600, 1024);
}

};
```

I've tried adding and removing the 'framework' parameter.
my versions are:
protractor 2.1.0
jasmine v2.3.1
jasmine-core v2.3.4

Thanks.

Comment: how do you run protractor? Directly with protractor bin, or with some grunt runner/gulp?

Comment: directly (terminal - protractor protractor.conf.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is a typo : `capabilities:` extra t.

Comment: Happens to the best of us :D